# how to convert all in file to lowercase?

Tags: c++, function

I am having trouble getting started with a program. I need to read in each word from a file, then convert it to lower case. I would like to `std::cout` each word after I find it. I assume I need to use `c_str()` some how. I am guessing I should use something like:

```
ofs.open(infile.c_str());
```

but how to lower case?

```
string[i] = tolower(string[i]);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `std::tolower()` function from [locale](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/locale). Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but here is a quick solution to your problem (as i understand it).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<locale>

int main(){
  std::string input;
  std::ifstream inputStream;
  inputStream.open("input.txt", std::ifstream::in);


  while(inputStream >> input){
    for(auto s : input)
    {
      std::cout << std::tolower(s, std::locale());
    }
    std::cout << " ";
  }

  return 0;
}
```